# Using the new OS Maps API (XYZ Version) and I keep getting 404

Tags: openlayers

My request URL is this -

https://api.os.uk/maps/raster/v1/zxy/Outdoor_3857/5/47/-765.png?key=apiKey

I'm passing a valid API key, but all I'm getting is a 404. Any ideas on where the get further information as to why it's a 404?

OpenLayers 6 in an Angular 9 application.

```
if (this.osMap == null) {
  console.log('centreLng:' + data.centreLongitude + ' centreLat:' + data.centreLatitude);
  this.osMap = new Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [new Tile({
        source: new XYZ({
          url: serviceUrl + '/Outdoor_3857/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=' + apiKey,
          projection: 'EPSG:27700',
          tileGrid: tilegrid
        })
      })


    ],
    view: new View({
      projection: 'EPSG:3857',
      center: fromLonLat([data.centreLongitude, data.centreLatitude]),
      zoom: 12
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: The Outdoor_3857 tiles should be used with source projection EPSG:3857 and a standard tilegrid.  See https://labs.os.uk/public/os-data-hub-examples/os-maps-api/zxy-3857-basic-map. (change the Mapbox dropdown to OpenLayers).  Source projection EPSG:27700 requires Outdoor_27700 tiles and a custom tilegrid,  For best results your view and source projections should be the same.

Comment: Are you trying to get a tile from outside the UK region? If I try yours I get 404, but https://api.os.uk/maps/raster/v1/zxy/Outdoor_3857/11/1008/662.png?key=$KEY works. Where are you expecting that tile to be on the world?

Comment: @Spacedman No tile anywhere in the world has a {y} value of -765

Comment: Map location centre should be Thetford, Norfolk, UK. I've tried a different example in my code and so map now renders ok, but my line features are not....

Comment: So should my centre and waypoints for my line features also be converted from lng lat to os gb grids if the map is rendered in EPSG:2700?

Comment: Your map is not EPSG:27000, your view projection is set to EPSG:3857

Comment: I've changed my map and view to be EPSG:27700 as spacedman suggested - keep them consistent, because I need to render the OS stylesheets for leisure and roads, which I've fond out are only available with  ESPG:27700, so having made those consistent and tested I need to supply the map centre in northings and eastings. Thanks everyone for the help so far - much appreciated...

Comment: fromLonLat can be used with any projection as long as it has been defined and registered using proj4 `fromLonLat([data.centreLongitude, data.centreLatitude], 'EPSG:27700')`

Comment: thanks guys all sorted now.....appreciate your help....

Answer (score 0):

Its a 404 because this tile isn't in the UK:

https://api.os.uk/maps/raster/v1/zxy/Outdoor_3857/5/47/-765.png?key=apiKey

it's probably not even on the planet, with that "-765" Y-value.

tiles that are in the UK work fine, for example:

https://api.os.uk/maps/raster/v1/zxy/Outdoor_3857/11/1008/662.png?key=$KEY

Restrict your map view to a valid UK location and it should only get 404s if you pan off the valid region.

Comment: My co-orindates are in longitude and latitude. As the map is rendered in PSG:27700 does that mean that I should provides co-oridnates for the map centre as easting and northings?

Comment: Its not rendered in EPSG:27700 though. You have 3857 set in your view and  `projection: 'EPSG:27700'` in the layer which will confuse the system since your layer is in 3857. Remove that and it should work - in 3857 throughout. If you want 27700 throughout then change the layer source and the view.